# play 1.2.x some code snippets or methods lie outside the current active transaction

Tags: transactions, playframework, ejb, jta

```
//start transaction 
public void testTras() {
do something //within current active transaction
code snippets  or  methods //without current active transaction
do something //within current active transaction
    }
//commit transaction
```

I want that code snippets  or  methods are outside of the current active transaction,while the code inside of the transaction.
I found many docs about JTA and Transaction propagation.I know EJB and spring is good at these though @Transactional(propagation),but I cannot find something associated with play.

Comment: Please be more specific what you want to achieve. Do you mean Jobs http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.7/jobs#anametasksTriggeringtaskjobsa?

Comment: well，I want to achieve that do something  in a transaction,then the transaction suspend,I do other thing without transaction before the transaction resume,     then transaction resume , Finally,I do something in the transaction.                                                       I know that It's achieved in spring and ejb though annotation with @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED).               But I do not know how to achieve in play .